# Embedded mongoid referencing

Tags: mongodb, reference, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, foreign-key-relationship

My `User` model `has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations`.

The `Conversation` model `embeds_many :messages`.

The `Message` model needs to have a `sender` and a `recipient`.

I was not able to find `referenced_in` at the [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html).

How do I assign the users in the message? I tried to follow something similar to [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015558/embedding-message-replies-inside-message-parent-with-mongodb-using-mongoid), but kept getting `BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize an object of class Mongoid::Relations::Referenced::In into BSON.`

**November 2013 Update**: `reference_in` no longer works with Mongoid 3.0? Changed to `belongs_to` and it seems to work the same.

Comment: you can easily replace `referenced_in` with `belongs_to`. Earlier they were synonyms, don't know about the latest version though.

Comment: Mongoid::Relations::Referenced::In is still a valid module. The problem is that referencing a Message document from the User document via a relational association is not allowed since the Message is embedded. So how to I reference the User in the Message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, my structure of the `Message` referencing the `User` was appropriate, and the serialization error was related to associating the Users with the Conversation. Here is my structure and the creation steps. I appreciate any feedback on better practices, thanks.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
end
```

```
class Conversation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  embeds_many :messages
end
```

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  embedded_in :conversation
  embeds_one :sender, class_name: 'User'
  embeds_one :recipient, class_name: 'User'

  field :content
  field :read_at, type: DateTime
  field :sender_deleted, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :recipient_deleted, type: Boolean, default: false

  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :sender, foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :recipient, foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
end
```

Where before I was trying to `@conversation.build(user_ids: [@user_one,@user_two])`, the appropriate way is to `@conversation.users.concat([@user_one,@user_two])`. Then you can simply `@conversation.messages.build(sender: @user_one, recipient: @user_two)`.